# Enable syntax highlighting on msysgit's version of vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, msysgit

I was wondering if there was a way to enable syntax highlighting on msysgit's "built in" vim. I'm specifically trying to get ruby highlighting to work, but nothing I have tried has enabled it. I'm guessing maybe the msysgit build works differently than the standard unix build.

Any pointers much appeciated.

Comment: Why not use the full Windows build?

Comment: Well I could install regular vim, but since I already have this prebundled with msysgit, I was wondering if I could make that version work. I understand and realize that installing the regular vim package would eliminate this need. But I'm honestly curious if I could be able to pull this off.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. After installing Vim for Windows, I noticed that it doesn't use unix style dot-directories (.vim) for configuration. So I pretty much copied over the vimfiles directory from my vim install to my profile and now I got full syntax highlighting in Vim under MSys.

Comment: Would you mind providing some walkthrough/sample code reflecting how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

After installing vim for Windows go to

C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\syntax

Copy Everything from that directory into

C:\Program Files\Git\share\vim\vim73\syntax

and voila, your MySysGit version of Vim will also have coloration for all the file types with an associated .vim file.